# How do i extract a link from a longer link using php?

Tags: php, regex

I was wondering if someone knows what the best method would be to extract a link from another link , Here's an example:

If I have links in the following format:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35HBFeB4jYg   OR
http://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080520042405AApM2Rv  OR
https://www.google.it/search?q=rap+tedesco&aq=f&oq=rap+tedesco&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l2.2287&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=migliori+programatori&oq=migliori+programatori&gs_l=serp.3..0i19j0i13i30i19l3.9986.13880.0.14127.14.10.0.4.4.0.165.931.6j4.10.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.tPmiWRyUVXA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=ffc0e9337f73a744&biw=1280&bih=699
```

How would I go about extracting only the web pages like so:

```
http://www.youtube.com
http://it.answers.yahoo.com
https://www.google.it
```

I was wondering if and what regular expression I could use with PHP to achieve this, also are regular expressions the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$link = "https://www.google.it/search?q=rap+tedesco";
$parseUrl = parse_url($link);
$siteName = $parseUrl['scheme']."://". $parseUrl['host'];
```

Using **Regexp**.

```
preg_match('@http(s?)://([\w]+\.){1}([\w]+\.?)+@',$link,$matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

[Codeviper Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jJon1h)

Answer (score 2):

There is a PHP function for parsing URLs: [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$url = 'http://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080520042405AApM2Rv';
$p = parse_url($url);
echo $p["scheme"] . "// . "$p["host"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to have the domain of the page, in PHP there exists a function called [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) that could help